# How can I create a task to fetch a page from a link in a tweet?

Tags: twitter, evernote, if-this-then-that

For example, if the tweet is

> The pros and cons of cloud hosting t.co/R1S9rcXW

I want ifttt to create a new note in Evernote with **body as the page linked** by the URL: t.co/R1S9rcXW, and NOT the URL itself.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I'd like to revive this question, as I am in exactly the same situation. Any new answers available?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the way your worded your question, you've already gone through IFTTT's process. Since there's no add-in for URL body, there's no way to capture it this way. You can see all the possible notes IFTTT can create in Evernote in [its channel description](http://ifttt.com/channels/evernote).

However, it is theoretically possible to have auto-clipping of page body because that's a feature of Evernote Web Clipper. You can ping IFTTT team on Twitter with this suggestion - they are very responsive.

Comment: My understanding is that the Evernote Web Clipper isn't automatic -- you have to actually load the webpage and click on the "clip" bookmarklet. I'd like a fully automatic solution, so that I can email a link to an account and have the PAGE ITSELF (not just the URL) archived in Evernote.